# Can man-made things be called the creations of Allah?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, creation

Can man-made things be called the creations of Allah?

Comment: If the man-made item does not cause haram or makru activity, Yes, indirectly, and with Allah's permission.  We say MashAllah

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, all that man creates is derived from the material that God has created.

For example, a man creates jewelry. These jewels are extracted and prepared by the human intellect (taken from God) from the mines God has created.

Comment: Does your opinion answer the question?

Comment: yes ...........

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely... YES.

ALLAH has created everything "Already" and left on his creatures to reveal them... Digging wells and taking out water doesn't mean water is created by "created" ones.. but he is only revealing. in the most advanced science, alpha, beta, gamma etc, rays, micro, sound waves, magnetic fields everything is just discovered.. 
and as in Quran - Sur-e-Rahman. ALLAH says..

> وَلَهُ الْجَوَارِ الْمُنشَآتُ فِي الْبَحْرِ كَالْأَعْلَامِ
>
> 055.024 His are the ships displayed upon the sea, like banners.

Whatever creature you see on the face of planet, is created by the ingredients created by THE CREATOR.